# How to set a font family to an entire Word document in Apache POI XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Is there a way to set a default font family to a word document generated by Apache POI instead of setting the font family to each `XWPFRun`?

Comment: What about a custom `createRun` method doing what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new method

```
public static XWPFRun createRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String     fontFamily, int fontSize, boolean bold, UnderlinePatterns underline){
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setFontFamily(fontFamily);
    run.setBold(bold);
    run.setUnderline(underline);
    run.setFontSize(fontSize);
    return run;
}
```

Then I call it like that:

```
XWPFParagraph paragraphHeader = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun runTextHeader = createRun(paragraphHeader, WordStyling.FONT_FAMILY_TIMES, WordStyling.FONT_SIZE_14);
```

or more generic:

```
public static XWPFRun createRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph){
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setFontSize(12);
    run.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
    return run;
}
```

Comment: Applying font family with run ,  is is updated  in object. But when opening docx file its not reflecting